# How to interpret the Lifecycle Mapping Dialog Box in M2E?

Tags: maven, maven-3, m2eclipse, m2e

In eclipse M2E 1.2.0 plugin when I got to a maven project properties, there is a lifecycle mapping dialog box, What is the meaning of the various columns in this dialog box. I have searched online for explanations, but did not find anything that clearly explained what the various columns means.

- What do each of the columns mean?
- Why dose configurator show up multiple times in Mapping for example in compiler:compile
- What do the different sources mean in the source column?

[image]

**Update:** This link good info about the lifecycle mapping https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Customizable+build+lifecycle+mapping+for+m2e+extensions+developers#Customizablebuildlifecyclemappingform2eextensionsdevelopers-Introduction

Comment: The link is dangling / ends in a "404 not found". Is there an updated URL or is the page gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What do each of the columns mean?

Plugin execution : a Maven goal which is discovered by m2eclipse as being bound to your pom.xml . For more details see [Maven: Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

> Why dose configurator show up multiple times in Mapping for example in compiler:compile

That might either be a bug or signal that the `compiler:compile` goal is mapped by multiple configurators.

> What do the different sources mean in the source column?

- uninteresting: it is completely ignored in Eclipse
- default: it is handled by a built-in handler from m2e, for instance the maven-resources-plugin
- extension: it is handled by a configurator external to m2e

Comment: What is the job of the configurator?

Comment: A configurator bridges between one or many Maven goals and their execution in Eclipse, so that Maven goals may be safely executed in Eclipse and take part in the normal Eclipse lifecycle - source / output folders configured, files immediately visible inside Eclipse etc.