# Maven install fired during Eclipse build

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-install-plugin

Lately, I've noticed that whenever I run a build in Eclipse also the `maven-install-plugin` is fired (copying the jars in my machine local artifacts repository).

I also tried to exclude it from the Eclipse build with `org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping` plugin but nothing changed.

Is that the standard behavior (that I honestly never realized) or is it my fault?

Stefano

Comment: how do you run a build?

Comment: From Eclipse I rely on "Build Automatically" option. From maven with `mvn clean test` or `mvn clean deploy` (depending on what I want to do) command line.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely isn't standard behaviour. See [How to interpret the Lifecycle Mapping Dialog Box in M2E?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329634/how-to-interpret-the-lifecycle-mapping-dialog-box-in-m2e) for more details on how to interpret the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

This is not standard behaviour.  Is it possible that this workspace has "install" defined under Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> "Goals to run when updating project configuration"? This setting defaults to "process-resources"